# Get a view by id in react js project

Tags: html, reactjs, axios

I am developing a project management tool with react js like notion or so , And I got all projects in a grid view by name date and priority and I created also a task kanban view in /tasks . My problem Is I want when the user clicks on a project in /project view it sends them to /tasks tasks of that specific project that He clicked on it .

[image]
[image]

helpful response will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Can you share your code please for more explantion

Comment: Please review the posting guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask